# Running development app on iPad wirelessly

Tags: xcode, ipad

I'm 99% sure that this isn't possible but thought id ask just in case.

I am an app developer, have a fully paid up developer license.

I am currently developing an app for someone who lives approx 3 hr drive away. Is there anyway i can get the app under development onto his iPad, without obviously having to make a 6hr round trip just to plug his iPad into my laptop to 2 minutes.

I've thought about sourcing a spare mac and sending him code with instructions with how to build it and download it, but my concern is giving him the source-code (he one of these people who thinks he god gift and will go messing).

Thanks

Comment: If I understand what you are looking to do, which is just allow him to use the app on his device, not develop it, then you could set up a certificate for ad-hoc deployment. Put his UDID into the profile, build an archive for ad-hoc deployment, and then send him the archive to install on his device. Google for ad-hoc deployment instructions. You'll basically be treating him as a beta tester.

Comment: so i was 99% wrong then lol, yeah that seems to be in the ball park of what i want to do, thats great thanks alot, time for some reading.

Comment: Test Flight is the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into using Test Flight! I've used this to distribute my own app to people across the state.

Comment: with the answer from auco, this was perfect answer, cant speak highly enough of this software, did job perfectly

Answer (score 1):

This is called Ad-Hoc distribution and necessary for beta testings. Generating production and development profiles is a tedious and quite complicated task, but once you did it three times, fairly straightforward:

1. obtain the **UDID** (this is not the serial number) of the device (can be seen in iTunes when clicking once on the devices serial number)
2. log in to your (paid) developer account and **register the device** for development (note: the total number of devices is restricted per year)
3. still in the developer account, **create an Ad-Hoc profile** for your app-id
4. load the profile in **Xcode** and check if your build-settings use the right profile
5. compile the app with a device as run target
6. create an **archive in Xcode** of your app
7. **export the app for ad-hoc distribution and sign it**
8. send the created file to your user
9. the user should add the app to his/her **iTunes library** and sync the device